# JMeter- graph generator plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a graph generator plugin. I want to create graphs after I input the users in GUI mode. Do I have to run the script in advance and then run it again in order to see the graphs?  I'm asking because it wants the 'JMeter Results File' which if I don't run, would not be there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make graphs: at run-time, or from old results. If you want to do the former, put it in your test and make sure you follow the instructions here:

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/#Generate-CSV-PNG-for-current-test-results

Note that, like many listeners, this has a fairly high performance cost, so it suggests you avoid using this while in GUI mode.

Alternatively, you can run your normal test without this listener, then run a second 'fake' test with it to generate your graphs:

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/#Generate-CSV-PNG-for-existing-previous-test-results

Comment: I saw the wiki and was unsure and I am still not cleared.  What does 'fake' test mean? we have to run it twice?

Comment: You create a second, smaller test that only runs a Dummy Sampler and this Listener. That's the 'fake' test. You only run your actually test once.

Comment: I ran the first test with 1 user and then the actual test with 300 users.  I see in the aggregatereportGUI file that it has 301 samples. Is it adding the previous run too? it should not be doing that.

Comment: Other way around: you want to run the actual test first. Don't include the Graph Generator. That test needs to have some sort of data writer that creates the file that you're going to be using. THEN you run the fake test that pulls its data from the file you created earlier.

Comment: I followed the former instructions without configuring the graph generator listener, but I don't see any png generated in my results folder. Am I doing anything wrong?